# Google+ Api working on device through android studio but not after deployment of the app on playstore

Tags: android, api, google-plus

I added the Google+ login API into my app and it worked perfectly while running it from Android Studio. But after I deployed it on the play store I am no longer able to sign in from Google+. 
I started with downloading the JSON configuration file and pasted it in the app folder and it was working just fine.
I generated the signed APK from Android Studio and uploaded it to google play.
I referred the following link
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

Comment: did you get a solution?